# angularjs link happens before replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following code snippet I need to pull the callclass attribute off the element AFTER the template has been compiled and replaced.  Whenever I try and get the attr object it references the parent element `<servicedesk>` not the replaced template on which the attributes exist.  How can I fix this?

```
app.directive('servicedesk', ['_sys_ctx', '_sys_servicedesk', '_sys_dictionary',
    function(_sys_ctx, _sys_servicedesk, dictionary) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: "partials/directives/servicedesk.html",
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                scope.data = _sys_servicedesk.retrieve(_sys_ctx);
                scope.scopename = "servicedesk_directive";

                var callclasses = dictionary.define('callclass');
                console.log(callclasses);
                attr.$observe('callclass', function(value) {
                    console.log(value)
                });
                scope.callclass = callclasses[attr.callclass];
            }

        }
    }
]);
```

Here is the template

```
<card ng-repeat="record in data" name="{{record.name}}" callclass="{{record.class}}">
    <header>{{callclass}}</header>
    <div class="calldetail">
        <div class="userimg">
            <img src="{{record.picture}}" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ul class="custinfo">
            <li class="name">
                <h3>{{record.name}}</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="phone">
                <h3>{{record.phone}}</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="email">
                <h3>{{record.email}}</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="summary">
            {{record.summary}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="description">
                {{record.description}}
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="status">
                {{record.status}}
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</card>
```

And the view that the servicedesk element resides in has nothing more than this

```
<servicedesk></servicedesk>
```

If it is relevant the view has its own controller as well.  Everything renders fine except for the callclass because when I try to even log the `elem` or `attrs` objects from inside the link function is references the `<servicedesk>` element not the replacement template.

Comment: Can you include the html template where you use the directive as well as partials/directives/servicedesk.html?

Comment: I've updated my question with those details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add property `replace: true` to your directive return object, so your `<servicedesk>` element will be replaced by your template an you could access to `attrs` of your `<card>` tag.